# Force Skype to open on specific display

Tags: osx, display, skype

When using multiple displays on OS X, we get the option to assign applications to one of them:

[image: screenshot]

However, Skype happily violates those assignments and always opens on the display on which I last clicked something. I assume it's trying to be smarter than the user again.
Since I want it to open on display 2, and my dock is on display 1 (which means I'll be clicking things on display 1), this annoys me.

Is there any <s>staple gun</s> software I could use to forcefully pin Skype to the display I want to have it on?
Or maybe one that reports a fake display count to Skype, so Skype can "see" only display 2?

I know I could ultimately use a VM to jail Skype in another window which I could then put wherever I want, but... well, it seems a little overkill.

Comment: What graphics card is being used?

Comment: @Terry NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780M 4096 MB